# How to retrieve array value from mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a data in mongoDB

```
"EMP_ID" : "1000",
"EMP_NAME" : "JIM",
"DEPARTMENT" : [
 {
     "DEPARTMENT_ID" : 1,
     "CONTACTS" : [
     {
        "MOBILE" : 102,
        "PHONE" : "1",
     }
  ]
}
```

How to retrieve mobile from the above data in mongo shell?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `db.col.findOne()` finds the document you're looking for:

```
db.col.findOne().DEPARTMENT.CONTACTS[0].MOBILE
```

should do it.

Comment: db.coll.findOne().DEPARTMENT[0].CONTACTS[0].MOBILE is working fine for me. Thanks

Comment: db.col.findOne({'DEPARTMENT[0].CONTACTS[0].MOBILE':"102"}) returns null. what im doing wrong here?